# Connect to google.com via ssl

Tags: php, ssl

Im using this code

```
$sock = fsockopen("ssl://google.com", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); 
if (!$sock) die("$errstr ($errno)\n"); 
fputs($sock, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n"); 
fputs($sock, "Host: google.com\r\n"); 
fputs($sock, "\r\n"); 
$headers = ""; 
while ($str = trim(fgets($sock, 4096))) 
$headers .= "$str\n"; 
$body = ""; 
while (!feof($sock)) 
$body.= fgets($sock, 4096); 
fclose($sock); 
echo '<div>'.$headers.'</div>'; 
echo '<div>'.$body.'<div>';
```

I receive page with this:

> HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently Location: https://www.google.com/
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Thu, 12 Dec 2013 11:03:07
> GMT Expires: Sat, 11 Jan 2014 11:03:07 GMT Cache-Control: public,
> max-age=2592000 Server: gws Content-Length: 220 X-XSS-Protection: 1;
> mode=block X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
> 301 Moved
>
> The document has moved here.

Where did I go wrong? Why i need to use ssl? Can i just write https? If i write https then i will receive error.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the site by the root domain "google.com".  The server is trying to redirect you to the subdomain that actually contains the site:  "www.google.com.  Add the "www." subdomain prefix and you will not get a 301 redirect anymore.